# AJAX post request, an object that includes an array and other objects, can't be parsed correctly into rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

What I want is to get a proper parameter, if you see the parameter been logged can you tell me if the problem's in my JavaScript?

First run the `runMe` function

```
 Ajax: function()
{
  var xmlhttp, bComplete = false;
  try { xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); }
  catch (e) { try { xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
  catch (e) { try { xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); }
  catch (e) { xmlhttp = false; }}}
  if (!xmlhttp) return null;
  this.connect = function(sURL, sMethod, sVars, fnDone)
  {
    if (!xmlhttp) return false;
    bComplete = false;
    sMethod = sMethod.toUpperCase();

    try {
      if (sMethod == "GET")
      {
        xmlhttp.open(sMethod, sURL+"?"+sVars, true);
        sVars = "";
      }
      else
      {
        xmlhttp.open(sMethod, sURL);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Method", "POST "+sURL+" HTTP/1.1");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
          "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", sVars.length);
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && !bComplete)
        {
          bComplete = true;
          fnDone(xmlhttp);
        }};
      xmlhttp.send(sVars);
    }
    catch(z) { return false; }
    return true;
  };
  return this;
},
tOrigin: function(origin){
    this.origin = origin;
},
tObject: function(origins,url,apik){
    this.origins=origins; //this is an array
    this.url=url;
    this.apik=apik; 
    this.host= "http://localhost:3000/";//window.location.hostname;
}
    runMe: function(){
                    var t = new tObject(['this','word','word me please','and me please','word','word','okay','word','go','go'],window.location.href,"helloapik");
    //  console.log(t);

        ajax = new Ajax();
        ajax.connect("http://localhost:3000/","POST",JSON.stringify(t), callBackFunc)
    }
```

This is what I'm getting in my rails server log:

`Parameters:`

`{"{\"origins\":"=>{"{\"origin\":\"this\"},{\"origin\":\"word\"},{\"origin\":\"word me please\"},{\"origin\":\"and me please\"},{\"origin\":\"word\"},{\"origin\":\"word\"},{\"origin\":\"word\"},{\"origin\":\"okay\"},{\"origin\":\"word\"},{\"origin\":\"go\"},{\"origin\":\"go\"}"=>{",\"url\":\"file:///Users/waheed/Desktop/untitled.html\",\"apik\":\"helloapik\",\"host\":\"http://localhost:3000/\"}"=>nil}}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the whole jQuery library is too much overhead you could gut it and pick what you need.

In any case, I'd say this is a problem with how you parse serverside, there seems to be some trailing s Ruby magic going on, but without knowing your serverside code it is quite hard to tell what is going on.

Comment: actually you dont need to know the server side, if you know rails you would know why.

Comment: But you would probably need to fix the problem server side. I don't know rails, but after a bit of googling I'd suggest you look at what `raw_post()` has to offer, or try the content of `request.env['RAW_POST_DATA']`. I can't try it out, so this is just a forward of what Google tells me.

Comment: I'm someone that stands firm against jQuery.  While, I'm an anti-jQuery advocate, I do say that it is useful and can be borrowed-from, where it applies.  +1 for gutting it